# aws s3 sync missing to create root folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am archiving some folders to S3
Example: `C:\UserProfile\E21126\data` ....

I expect to have a folder structure in s3 like, `UserProfiles\E21126`.

Problem is it created the folders under `\E21126` and misses creating the root folder `\E21126`.

`Folds1.txt` contains these folders to sync:

```
G:\UserProfiles\E21126
G:\UserProfiles\E47341
G:\UserProfiles\C68115
G:\UserProfiles\C30654
G:\UserProfiles\C52860
G:\UserProfiles\E47341
G:\UserProfiles\C68115
G:\UserProfiles\C30654
G:\UserProfiles\C52860
```

my code below:

```
ForEach ($Folder in (Get-content "F:\scripts\Folds1.txt")) {
    aws s3 sync $Folder s3://css-lvdae1cxfs003-archive/Archive-Profiles/ --acl bucket-owner-full-control --storage-class STANDARD
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will upload all the folders with their names excluding the path. If you want to include the UserProfiles in the S3 bucket then you will needs to include that in the key. You need to upload them to the S3 bucket with specifying the key name

```
aws s3 sync $Folder s3://css-lvdae1cxfs003-archive/Archive-Profiles/UserProfiles --acl bucket-owner-full-control --storage-class STANDARD
```

---

and If your files have different name instead of UserProfiles string then you can get the parent path and then fetch the leaf to get the username from the string

```
PS C:\> Split-Path -Path "G:\UserProfiles\E21126"
G:\UserProfiles

PS C:\> Split-Path -Path "G:\UserProfiles" -Leaf -Resolve
UserProfiles
```

Comment: Thank you KayD, appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

If you were to modify the text file to contain:

```
E21126
E47341
C68115
```

Then you could use the command:

```sh
ForEach ($Folder in (Get-content "F:\scripts\Folds1.txt")) {
    aws s3 sync G:\UserProfiles\$Folder s3://css-lvdae1cxfs003-archive/Archive-Profiles/$Folder/ --acl bucket-owner-full-control --storage-class STANDARD
}
```

Note that the folder name is included in the destination path.